# Express SSE - Broadcast to session users

Tags: typescript, express, server-sent-events

I am writing a REST API in Express.js with Typescript. The API is based around a randomly generated "room token" -- a string that refers to a particular instance of session data. The room token may be shared between multiple clients -- typically by having one user create a new room, then they copy-paste a URL to share with their friends/colleagues that includes the room token.

Within this API I need to support Server Sent Events (SSE). It appears the only SSE middleware for Express that has Typescript types is [ExpreSSE](https://github.com/toverux/expresse).

So, what I'm trying to do is implement a "broadcasted" SSE (I use the term broadcast loosely; I am aware at the network layer it's really 1-to-1) where each event only goes to those who have subscribed to a specific room token.

To illustrate this, imagine the following conversation:

- Client A calls `/api/subscribeToChangeNotification` with the data payload `{token: '12345'}`.
- Client B calls `/api/subscribeToChangeNotification` with the data payload `{token: '6789'}`.
- Client C calls `/api/subscribeToChangeNotification` with the data payload `{token: '12345'}`.
- An event occurs server-side that kicks off the SSE code flow. This event pertains to token 12345, so the SSE message is sent *only* to Clients A and C.
- Another SSE occurs for token 6789, and the message is sent *only* to Client B.

The two ways documented for ExpreSSE to handle broadcast are using a so-called `Hub` object, where:

- Way #1 involves creating a new `Hub` for *each client* using the `sse` middleware. This is not what I want, because then a "broadcast" will only go to one individual client, not *every* client subscribed to a given token.
- Way #2 involves setting a global `Hub` and passing it into the `sseHub` middleware.

I need a "Way #3" that lets me specify the Hub to use based on the payload of the request when the client calls `subscribeToChangeNotification`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up doing it. The first line of the `middleware` function calls into my app-specific session global data (a `Map`) which creates and keeps a reference to a new `Hub` for each distinct room token. The remainder of the `middleware` function is just copy-pasted from `sseHub()` from the source code of ExpreSSE. I then use `dynamicSseHub()` in my SSE API as middleware.

```
/**
 * SSE middleware that configures an Express response for an SSE session, installs `sse.*` functions on the Response
 * object, as well as the `sse.broadcast.*` variants.
 *
 * @param options An ISseMiddlewareOptions to configure the middleware's behaviour.
 */
function dynamicSseHub(options: Partial<ISseMiddlewareOptions> = {}): Handler {

    function middleware(req: Request, res: ISseResponse, next: NextFunction): void {
        let hub : IHub = sessions.get(req.body.toString()).hub;
        //=> Register the SSE functions of that client on the hub
        hub.register(res.sse);

        //=> Unregister the user from the hub when its connection gets closed (close=client, finish=server)
        res.once('close', () => hub.unregister(res.sse));
        res.once('finish', () => hub.unregister(res.sse));

        //=> Make hub's functions available on the response
        (res as ISseHubResponse).sse.broadcast = {
            data: hub.data.bind(hub),
            event: hub.event.bind(hub),
            comment: hub.comment.bind(hub),
        };

        //=> Done
        next();
    }

    return compose(sse(options), middleware);
}
```